# What is the Difference between Archiving and Purging in Oracle database?

Tags: oracle, archive

I would like to know the main difference between **Archiving** and **Purging** in any database we use.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question.  Archiving can have several different meanings, such as archive logs, flashback archives, and the new 12c feature [in-database archiving](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17613/part_lifecycle.htm#VLDBG14154).

Answer (score 8):

Purge Process

Purging is the process of freeing up space in the database or of deleting obsolete data that is not required by the system. The purge process can be based on the age of the data or the type of data.

Archive Process

Archiving is the process of backing up the obsolete data that will be deleted during the purge process. During the archive process, data will be moved from the main transactional tables to the backup tables.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider data archiving and purging in database terminology, then *archiving* means moving the data from a main operational database to other secondary or backup database, or even on a less expensive storage system. *Purging* means removing the data completely. You can go with both the techniques combined by archiving the data to another database server or backup system, retain it there for a certain period, depending upon the retention policy, and then purge that data from the system.